# Create New File From Custom Explorer Bar Button

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-explorer

I want to create a custom button on my Windows Explorer toolbar to create a new blank text document, similar to the "New Folder" button that is already there.

[image]

Following [these steps](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/add-the-up-button-to-the-explorer-command-bar-in-windows-7/3877/), I was able to create my button and get it running a custom VBScript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(WshShell.CurrentDirectory & "\NewTextDocument.txt", True)
objFile.Close
Wscript.Quit
```

However, the value of `WshShell.CurrentDirectory` is `C:\Windows\system32`. (I think this is because the command being called is `wscript.exe` which is in that directory.).

**How can I get the directory where the Explorer window is opened up to?**

--
Somewhat related: I have been getting a "Permission denied" error when I run this script. I was assuming this was because the `system32` directory is protected. Are there any other precautions to ensure the script will be allowed to create a file?

Thanks.

Comment: I know only one way - create and register inproc COM server instead of VBScript. COM server must implement IObjectWithSite, IInitializeCommand, IObjectWithSelection, IExplorerCommand, IExplorerCommandState. It is necessary to write CLSID of COM server under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\YouCommandName key in ExplorerCommandHandler value. And it will be available to get current folder inside IObjectWithSite.SetSite.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different approach.

Use the shell not file system to do what you want.

Here's two sample scripts using the type of objects you need.

```
'Const NETHOOD = &H14& 'fonts
'Const NETHOOD = &H12& 'Network
Const NETHOOD = &H11& 'My Comp
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(NETHOOD)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path
Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
    For x = 1 to 79

        Properties = Properties & vbtab & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(ObjItem, x)
    Next
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Name" & Properties 
    Properties=""
Next
```

and to find right window

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
Next
```